# Unable to update req.user in a middleware policy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I am building an application on sails js and am trying to set a local value in a policy middleware. I am unable to do so, please help.

This is NOT working

```
    var perms = {"view":true,"add":true,"edit":false};
    // My req.user comes after deserialize (working well)
    req.user.perms = perms;
    res.locals.user = req.user;
```

where are the code below is working

```
    var perms = {"view":true,"add":true,"edit":false};
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    res.locals.user.perms = perms;
```

I am trying to access {{user.perms}} in a handlebars template

I guess I am doing something conceptually wrong in the first code, please help.

Comment: The code you show looks right to me. Can you show the rest of the chain? Any other policies interfering? Do you do anything heavy in the controller method? Is your template server-side or client-side?

Comment: You mean, req.user is being updated somewhere later in other policies / middleware. I will check it once. I do not change anything in controller, intact req.user is not event called. Its server side rendering using handlebars.

Comment: One Question here, I realize that `req.user` is a mongodb document that was assigned, does it cause any issue?

can i set a value of the returned mongo doc like `req.user.perms` original document did not have perms attribute

Comment: yes that answers my question. And there should be no issues with modifying properties of a document from mongodb. I would say it must be some issue with how data is being passed to your template (or into `res.locals` and then into your template)...

Comment: I've never used handlebars, so I would be guessing about specifics. But... if the second code block is working, doesn't that accomplish what you want?

Comment: Got the issue! It was basically a mongoDb document that was causing not allowing to set the permission because it wasn't in the model, I added before assigning user to req.user, i added `user.toObject()` and it got fixed.

Comment: you should answer your own question with your solution in case others end up here from google.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the issue.

The `user` was being set in passport deserialize after executing `User.find()`, so the `req.user` was being set as a MongoDB document and because the `User` model did not have perms attribute, I was not able to set the value.

The answer was to convert MongoDB Document to plain JSON Object before sending to callback.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function (userSession, done) {

    User.findOne({"_id":userSession._id},function(err, user){

        done(err, user.toObject())
    })

}
```

Now this works

```
req.user.perms = perms;
res.locals.user = req.user;
```